# How to check if an SSM2220 IC is authentic and not fake?

Tags: transistors

I ordered this chip from an unreliable source and would like to know if there is any way to measure, test, or otherwise check to see if it is an authentic [SSM2220](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/SSM2220.pdf).

I want to know if this is a real pair of precisely matched transistors with extremely low noise. In my design it works as an exponential current source and the chip worked fine, so they are definitely transistors.

Comment: Why did you use an unreliable source?

Comment: @Andyaka Because it's cheaper or not available in authorised stores

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki [this supplier](https://www.chip-components.com/instcok/2567228/SSM2220.html) MAY be useful.

Comment: @Andyaka  The part is obsolete and has no clear replacement. Stock is mainly held by end of line inventory sellers. Digikey list the part as available "from marketplace" but in tube quantities at almost $500. || Other suppliers that I've not heard of and that you may have list it in the $25 + to ++ range. Whether they are reliable I know not.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki Many choices [here](https://www.digipart.com/part/SSM2220) - most uncertain

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki Are you absolutely sure you need such a precise part? Is this for some new design? Maybe if you posted more details about your design you could get some useful suggestions for a different circuit to achieve the same goals. Relying on obsolete parts for new designs could be a really bad investment, even if the specs of the part are stellar. If your design is successful you may regret it down the road, when you are asked for more boards, but you cant provide more because the part is "unobtanium". Maybe your design could be adapted to a newer, widely available part..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's actually a fairly simple way to check that the parts are genuine. The SSM2220 is special because of its extremely low offset voltage, which is unmatched by any currently available dual PNP transistor, which means that a fake necessarily has much worse offset.

To test, build the following simple circuit with one SSM2220:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9oTaZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the voltage measured by voltmeter VM1 is less than 250µV (0.25mV) for all(!) of the SSM2220 you purchased, they're almost definitely genuine. If there are any outliers, you got junk.

While it's not absolutely required that the resistors have 0.1% tolerance, they *must* be matched very closely (ideally within 0.1%, hence the suggestion to just use very accurate resistors). If you don't have any 0.1% resistors on hand, you can select a matched pair of 1% metal-film parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a great and simple advice.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I would stress more that the point here is resistor matching, rather than absolute accuracy. Finding matched pairs is somewhat easier than 0.1% parts.

Answer (score 10):

If you have the equipment (and skills to use it) to measure the datasheet parameters that would provide some assurance, but even if it passes that would not guarantee that the particular sample is genuine.

If it **fails** to meet all specifications, of course, it’s likely not a genuine non-reject part. It could also be a genuine part but used (possibly damaged, or not).

If I wanted to prove they were not genuine, I’d probably start with a DC measurement of offset voltage which would weed out crude fakes and proceed to build the datasheet noise measurement circuit, Fig, 19, which calls for a suitable spectrum analyzer, if it passes the Vos test. The offset measurement would use something like the amplifier circuit in Fig. 8 of the [MAT02 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/obsolete-data-sheets/mat02.pdf). Of course you would omit the offset adjust pot and use precision matched collector resistors.

But for a few pieces it will be easier to trash the suspect parts and start over with 99.9% known-good components.

Answer (score 6):

Some manufacturers keep internal lists of device lot codes for traceability purposes, and for detecting possible counterfeit devices. Such lists of lot codes are not publicly available.

See [LM3S8C62 Misbonded/Counterfeit part?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/arm-based-microcontrollers-group/arm-based-microcontrollers/f/arm-based-microcontrollers-forum/1128630/lm3s8c62-misbonded-counterfeit-part/4204344?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=counterfeit#4204344) for an example response from Texas Instruments customer support.

Found the following response on the Analog devices forum in [ADRF5040BCPZ 5-digit lot number from top mark.Mine has 60572.Need to know the date code](https://ez.analog.com/rf/f/q-a/556941/adrf5040bcpz-5-digit-lot-number-from-top-mark-mine-has-60572-need-to-know-the-date-code):

> Unfortunately, we are unable to provide information about parts in the EngineerZone community based on their markings. We suggest going back to your point of purchase to get this information. Note that ADI only provides warranty coverage or any quality, reliability, failure analysis, applications, or other support on products purchased through ADI authorized distributors and sales offices. To ensure you are receiving unused, legitimate ADI product, please ensure all purchases are made through the ADI authorized distributors and sales offices listed on our website at: https://www.analog.com/en/about-adi/corporate-information/sales-distribution.html

So, if forced to use an unreliable source difficult to see how you would get any support from Analog Devices to trace if your parts are authentic.

Since the SSM2220 is obsolete, would it be easier for a re-design to use a different active part which is available from an authorised supplier?

I realise this hasn't directly answered your question about how to test a SSM2220 to see if it meet's the manufacturers published datasheet parameters, but as Spehro Pefhany has already noted that is not simple.

Comment: The huge problem with the SSM2220 is that ADI was the last manufacturer making a tightly matched low-noise PNP pair. There are no alternatives left.

Comment: @JonathanS. Is the BCM857 not well enough matched? Nexperia's still making those.

Comment: @Hearth These are SMD, right? I need DIP package for this particular design.

Comment: @Hearth The BCM857 guarantees 10% gain and 2mV Vbe matching, while the SSM2220 gets you 3% gain and 0.2mV Vbe. The latter is especially important for circuits using the exponential behavior of BJTs, which means that the SSM2220 is an order of magnitude better for those applications. It's pretty sad to see such parts get discontinued with no replacement. At least the NPN version is still available, which makes circuit design is a little more difficult, but at least not impossible.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki If it's a retrofit, it wouldn't be too hard to put a BCM857 on a tiny breakout board. Though as Jonathan S. points out, the matching might not be quite enough depending on what your application is.

Comment: Alfa RPAR makes the [AS395](https://www.alfarzpp.lv/eng/sc/AS395.pdf), which is a different pinout, but through-hole, dual PNP, 3% gain-matched, Vbe matched to 100uV. Should be available from a number of synth-DIY dealers (synthcube, thonk, etc.)